# Racket Scheme: Basic example with Swindle

Tags: scheme, racket

I wanted to write a small prototype for something, and one of my first thoughts was, that a multimethod-based implementation would be really cool.

While I have used GOOPS in the past with guile, I thought I would give racket a try this time. And googling quickly showed that a tiny clos implementation "swindle" was available and distributed with racket:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/swindle/index.html?q=

After instaling racket, I could not load `#lang swindle`

```
#lang swindle
```

`racket -f test.rkt`

```
 % racket -f test.rkt 
standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: (submod swindle reader)
  collection: "swindle"
  in collection directories:
   /Users/holgerpeters/Library/Racket/6.1.1/collects
   /usr/local/Cellar/plt-racket/6.1.1/share/racket/collects
   /usr/local/Cellar/plt-racket/6.1.1/share/racket/pkgs/racket-lib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using the Homebrew `plt-racket` package, which is a distribution of **Minimal Racket**, which doesn't include all the packages by default.

The quick fix would be to install the `swindle` package yourself. Just use the `raco` command-line tool:

```
raco pkg install swindle
```

However, you might find having a full Racket installation helpful. The DrRacket IDE is fairly solid, and it isn't included in the minimal distribution.

The easiest way to install Racket is via the distributions [available through Racket's website](http://download.racket-lang.org/). Alternatively, if you want to install a non-minimal version of Racket on Mac OS X using a package manager, you can use the Homebrew extension, [Cask](http://caskroom.io/). It provides a full version of Racket available through the following command:

```
brew cask install racket
```